# Django принимает файл из формы как текст

Tags: python, html, django

Пытаюсь получить из HTML-формы файл, вместо него в запросе отправляется просто название файла.

Форма:

```
<form method="post" action="load_game">
    {% csrf_token %}
    Name: <input type="text" name="name">
    Description: <input type="text" name="desc">
    Photos: <input type="file" multiple accept="image" name="photos">
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

Представление:

```
def load_game(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
       ...
    if request.method == "POST":
        login = request.COOKIES.get("GameCaseLogin")
        if login is None or not User.objects.filter(login=login).exists():
            return HttpResponse("Error. Clean cookies and try again", status=422)
        user = User.objects.get(login=login)
        game = Game(author=user,
                    name=request.POST.get("name", "UNDEFINED_NAME"),
                    description=request.POST.get("desc", "UNDEFINED_DESCRIPTION"),
                    rating=0.0)
        game.save()
        picture = GamePhoto(game=game, photo=request.FILES["photos"])
        picture.save()
        return HttpResponse(picture.photo)
```

Модель:

```
class GamePhoto(models.Model):
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="game")
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=f"game_photos/")
```

Запрос:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ошибку выдает по ключу 'photos'

Comment: Забыли про `enctype="multipart/form-data"` и Django тут ни при чём